# efficiently iterate over the not set values in a massive bit array in Java

Tags: java, bitarray, loops

I got a massive bit array saved as a byte array, which represent all signed int values (4,294,967,295).

```
byte[] bitArray = byte[536870912];
```

Each byte in the array represents 8 numbers, one for each bit. That means byte[0] stores 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and byte[1] stores 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 etc.

I use this to store a huge table, where I can either set numbers to either true or false (0 or 1). I got some rather efficient methods to check if a bit is set and to set a bit (only using bitwise operators).

Now I need to iterate this table over and over to find the bits that are set to 0. Of course it would be rather efficient to only store the numbers I want to iterate over, so I don't need to check them all each time, but there are so many numbers that storing them in an ArrayList uses a lot of memory.

How can I efficiently iterate multiple times over the not set values in the bit array?

Comment: What fraction of all numbers are likely to be set to true? If it's very small you could use a `Set<Integer>` to store the true numbers, rather than using `byte[536870912]`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp It's very random.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I agree it's a lot, but that's not of my choosing. I need to use the not set bits over and over. I totally get that I should just go over it once and make an ordered list / array list of it, but then I would store them as actual numbers. I only need to store like 10% of them though, but they would use at least 32 times as much space... :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I efficiently iterate over this bit array?

One way to do this is to use a BitSet.  This will both scan a `long[]` examining 64-bits at a time but it's underlying methods are turned into intrinsics. i.e. single machine code instructions which are likely to be faster than anything you can write in Java.

If you really want to write this yourself, I suggest you look at how BitSet works and copy it's code. (Or use BitSet)

I suggest you have a look at the methods Long's [numberOfLeadingZeros(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-long-) [numberOfTrailingZeros(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfTrailingZeros-long-) [bitCount(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#bitCount-long-)

An intrinsic is a method the JVM "recognizes" and replaces with specialised machine code instruction(s)  This can make it much faster than copying the code and running the same code in Java.

> How can I efficiently iterate multiple times over the not set values in the bit array?

In BitSet it uses the following loop

```
public int nextSetBit(int fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("fromIndex < 0: " + fromIndex);

    checkInvariants();

    int u = wordIndex(fromIndex);
    if (u >= wordsInUse)
        return -1;

    long word = words[u] & (WORD_MASK << fromIndex);

    while (true) {
        if (word != 0)
            return (u * BITS_PER_WORD) + Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(word);
        if (++u == wordsInUse)
            return -1;
        word = words[u];
    }
}
```

Note: this is examining 64-bits in each iteration.

Comment: Bah, I think I messed up that question a bit, see my edit. >_<

Comment: Note that [BitSet.html#nextSetBit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29) does pretty much exactly what OP wants.

Comment: BitSet is interesting! Is there any way I could save the exact numbers I'm looking for in a more memory efficient way than in Integer objects in an ordered list or an array list etc. The order actually matters, but just that they are in numerical order. I expect only around 10% to not be set.

Comment: @HorseSMith an Integer object uses 24 bytes so you will find a bit set hard to beat unless your 10% is not evenly distributed eg IP a dresses are not. In any case it only uses 1/2 GB and saving a bit more memory is unlikely to be worth it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you saved my day... again! our paths intersect a lot on stack overflow :) Thanks a lot!